VStack and Spacer placement in SwiftUI
Here is my sample code for my current View. I want my Vstack(with the brown bg) to be starting from top (having few top padding). I put a Spacer() for that but seems not quite working. Any help?
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Background Image
            Image("companyLaunch")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "command")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: horizontalSizeClass == .regular ? 170 : 200, height: horizontalSizeClass == .regular ? 40 : 60)
                    .padding(.top, 20)
                
                Image(systemName: "building")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: horizontalSizeClass == .regular ? 300 : 200, height: horizontalSizeClass == .regular ? 225 : 150)
                
                
                Text("One place\nfor all your work.")
                    .font(.titilliumWebRegular(size: 25))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                
                Text("Best-in-class system to advance your business.\nGet in Touch anytime, anywhere, track all activities\nand customizable based on needs.")
                    .font(.titilliumWebRegular(size: 15))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(height: 1)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 40)
                
                mainContent
                
                
            }
            .background(Color.brown)
            Spacer()
        }
    }



I would suggest setting the background image using a .background modifier on the ZStack, because you are scaling it using .scaledToFill(). If it is contained inside the ZStack, it will cause the ZStack to overflow. See this answer for more explanation.

Default alignment for ZStack is .center, also you put Spacer() in ZStack so it just expand entirely. A solution is changing alignment of ZStack to .top:
ZStack(alignment: .top) { // <- change alignment here

Another solution is wrap your brown View in another VStack then add Spacer to it:
VStack {
    ... brown view
        .background(Color.brown)
    Spacer()
}



Good. I didn't know ZStack has an alignment setting as well. So much to learn.

Btw, 2nd solution is not good for me. Contents messed up after orientation changed to landscape.

1st solution is not good for me when orientation change to landscape also

@ZinWinHtet checkout Benzy Neez brilliant's comment, the error occur truely because of what he said
